# Behavior of calling finish() on activity that has focus

Tags: android, android-activity

What would happen if the finish() method is called in the code of an Activity that currently has the focus because another Activity intended it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If use finish() method that activity will be destroyed and the previous activity still in running and in activity stack.

Answer (score 2):

When `finish()` is called, that activity is destroyed. The previous activity that is still running would then be shown.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()